# How do I Start/Stop an animation in Unity 5.3 (C#)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I'm trying to start and stop my walk animation, in unity 5.3.

Something like this.

```
If(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow)){ 
GetComponent<Animator>().Play("WalkAnimation"); 
} 

else If(!Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow)){ 
GetComponent<Animator>().Stop("WalkAnimation"); 
}
```

But somehow this doesn't really work out for my. 
thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Unity provides very nice tutorials on various subjects including [animator scripting](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/animation/animator-scripting?playlist=17099)

Answer (score -1):

While this doesn't directly answer your question, using direct commands to animation is a legacy functionality, nowadays we use Mekanim animation state machine:

[You can find a video tutorial here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xx21y9eJq1U)

Comment: If it doesn't answer the question, don't answer the question.